# Nancy Autofac prevent container dispose

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, nancy

Is there any possibility to prevent Nancy from rearranging container with new requests? I've created this simplyfied code to show my problem. Constructor for ConsoleWriter is called every single time and don't want this to happen. Of course I could make ConsoleWriter a singleton, but my real-life problem is more complex and making dozen classes singletons can be problematic. So, is there any possibility for forcing Nancy into acknowledgind that object ConsoleWriter already exist and use him instead of creating new one?

NancyApp.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Bootstraper.cs:

```
class Bootstrapper : AutofacNancyBootstrapper
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public void Start()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ConsoleWriter>()
               .SingleInstance();
               //.ExternallyOwned()
               //.PropertiesAutowired();

        builder
            .RegisterType<ClientAPI>()
            .SingleInstance()
            .AutoActivate();

        builder
            .RegisterType<RestAPI>();
            //.ExternallyOwned()
            //.PropertiesAutowired();

        _container = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

ConsoleWriter.cs:

```
public class ConsoleWriter : IConsoleWriter
{
    private int _random_number;
    public ConsoleWriter()
    {
        _random_number = new Random().Next(0, 1000);
    }

    public int Value()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_random_number);
        return _random_number;
    }
}
```

RestApi.cs:

```
public class RestAPI :NancyModule
{
    public RestAPI(ConsoleWriter consoleWriter)
    {
        Post["/click_1"] = param =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("clicked_on_1");

            int value = consoleWriter.Value();

            return value.ToString();
        };

        Post["/click_2"] = param =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("clicked_on_2");

            return "CLICKED_ON_2";
        };

        Post["/click_3"] = param =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("clicked_on_3");

            return "CLICKED_ON_3";
        };
    }
}
```

Output:

> Random number is: 75
>
> Random number is: 342
>
> Random number is: 995

**Edit:** I've cleared code out of misleading issues.

Comment: I miss that when I refactored the code. Sadly, deleting doubled call doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Does commenting out `.ExternallyOwned()
               .PropertiesAutowired();` help?

Comment: Sadly, but no. I started without them, but I've added them because in some topic they advised to use it, but with or without them Nancy works exactly the same.

Comment: If you comment out the `builder.RegisterType<ConsoleWriter>()
               .SingleInstance();` lines, what happens (what random numbers are outputted)?